# Display the filter content not excerpt in Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting post excerpt content with this code.

```
echo the_excerpt();
```

And also I am getting full post. content with this code

```
$content = get_the_content();
echo $content;
```

But I don't want full content. I want to show the content without the excerpt content.

if the full content is this:
"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."

excerpt is this:
"Lorem Ipsum"

then the content without excerpt will be show this:
"is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."

I want to set word count while displaying the content without excerpt.

I have tried multiple code to achieve this but not get any solution. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: The excerpt is not necessarily the first paragraph of the content in WordPress, which is why I don't know of any method that returns the content without the excerpt. You will need to create a custom function that removes the first part of the content based on your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is not replacing HTML tags. I figured out some code which can replace tag also...

```
echo "<div id='precont'>";
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 250);
echo "...<a href='#viewmore'>View More</a>";
echo "</div>";




echo "<div id='viewmore'>";
$prefix = substr($content, 0, 250);
$result = str_replace($prefix, "", $content);
echo $result;
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call content function like that:

```
the_content( null, true );
```

null - to do not show "read more", and true - to remove initial text before <--more-->:
More in docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

Or if above not working for you, you can use not a nice solution, but 100% working with str_replace:

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$content = get_the_content();

$final_content = str_replace( $excerpt, '', $content );
```